# Constructor of Spring Boot RestController not invoked when using aspect

Tags: java, spring, aspectj, aspect

I am new to AOP and currently trying to implement an aspect for controller methods annotated with a custom annotation.
I allways get a *NullPointerException* on *repository* when *myFunction* is invoked. It seems that i have two instances of of the controller. One of them is instantiated without autowiring the repository. When i remove @MyAnnotation everything works as expected.

Can you give me any hint on how to force Spring/AspectJ to use my constructor?

My controller looks like:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/api")
public class MyController {
    private Repository repository;

    public MyController(Repository repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{variable1}", method = GET)
    @MyAnnotation
    public final FeatureCollection myFunction(
        final @PathVariable(required = true) long variable1
    ) {
        repository.findById(variable1);
        (...)
    }
}
```

The aspect:

```
@Aspect
public class MyAspect {
    @Around("@annotation(MyAnnotation)")
    public Object any(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
        return pjp.proceed();
    }
}
```

The configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
public class WebConfig {
    @Bean
    public MyAspect myAspect() {
        return new MyAspect();
    }
}
```

Comment: What's your Spring version?

Comment: The _Spring Boot Starter Parent_ version is 1.5.6.RELEASE

Comment: Ok so there is definitely no `@Autowired` needed, as mentionned in an answer. I'm gonna test it myself, I'm pretty sure that's due to the way the controller is proxyfied. I'm trying to reproduce and i'll come back at you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It comes from the fact that the annotated method is `final`.

If you can remove the `final` keyword, it'll work.

If you google something like "spring aop final methods", you'll find more info, but basically, when Spring creates the proxy, it generates a subclass from your original class, to wrap the call to super with your aspect. The problem is that a final method cannot be inherited by the subclass, so that makes it hard for the proxy to work. Therefore, a lot of limitations come from that, and AOP doesn't work that much with `final` stuff.

This limitation is mentioned in the docs, I don't think you'll get a workaround for it:

> 11.6 Proxying mechanisms
>
> ...
>
> `final` methods cannot be advised, as they cannot be overridden.

Hoping this will help you!

Comment: Thank you so much! I spent hours to find my mistake.

Answer (score 2):

Try to Annotate Constructor with @Autowired

```
@Autowired
public MyController(Repository repository) {
    this.repository = repository;
}
```

Comment: I think you need a @Qualifier annotation before the constructor parameter, too.

Comment: I already tried to annotate the constructor with @Autowired. But i am still getting the NPE.